# removeFrom is deleting all of my many-to-many associations

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm using Grails 1.2 and have the following many-to-many relationship setup:

```
class Employee {
    static belongsTo = Store
    static hasMany = [stores:Store]
}

class Store {
    static hasMany = [employees:Employee]
}
```

I seed some data in Bootstrap.groovy:

```
store1.addToEmployees(employee1).save()
store1.addToEmployees(employee2).save()
store1.addToEmployees(employee3).save()
```

This results in the following DB data:

```
| store_employees | 
----------------------------------
| store_id        | employee_id   |
|    1            | 1             | 
|    1            | 2             |
|    1            | 3             |
----------------------------------
```

Next, I try to remove a single employee from the store:

```
store.removeFromEmployees(employee1).save()
```

This results in **all** employees getting removed. Did I setup the relationship wrong or something?

Comment: What's the state after the remove but before the save?  i.e. break that last line into:

    store.removeFromEmployees(employee1);
    println store.employees;
    store.save();
    println store.employees;

EDIT: Added semi-colons.  Forgot about poor formatting in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I am not getting the same issue.

When I run this code using console plugin:

```
Store.list()*.delete() //clear so you can run script multiple times
Employee.list()*.delete()   //clear so you can run script multiple times

store1 = new Store().save()
 employee1 = new Employee()
 employee2 = new Employee()
 employee3 = new Employee()

store1.addToEmployees(employee1).save()
store1.addToEmployees(employee2).save()
store1.addToEmployees(employee3).save(flush:true)


Store.list()[0].removeFromEmployees(Employee.list()[0]).save()
```

The resulting state of DB (first added employee was removed):

```
EMPLOYEE
ID  VERSION
1   1
2   0
3   0

STORE
ID  VERSION
1   2

STORE_EMPLOYEES
EMPLOYEE_ID     STORE_ID
2   1
3   1
```

Comment: I didn't use the console but wrote the code in Bootstrap and an integration test. Could not reproduce the problem. Grails 1.2